# Codeigniter use same model for different project

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I am working on two websites and I need them to communicate to the same database. They are two separate codeigniter projects in different project folders in the htdocs folder of xampp.

In project A I have a model that already does what I need it to do. In project B, I need to use this model in my controller class. How can I do this? Thanks.

Right now, I have the full path to the model in the $this->load->model() method in my controller but it doesn't want to work so I don't think this is correct.

Comment: It won't work, because as you know it is on a different application. If you are planning to reuse a lot of the functions and code on site A. Make api calls to site A from Site B. REST application.

Answer (score 0):

You can't link two different projects to one. Each project work as standalone work space. So Project A's **View-Model-Controller** Cannot access inside Project B

**Tip:** You can copy that model from your Project A and place it on your Project B.
So in `database.php` you can connect same database and all works fine.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to figure it out by entering the path to the file location.

So,

$this->load->model('/path/to/model/modelName'); and it worked. True, we do have to assume these are being hosted on the same server.